# ls executes slowly on remote server

Tags: linux, performance, operating-systems, ls

I have a very strange problem, one that may be too difficult to diagnosis without machine access, but maybe someone here may be able to help.

I am using OS X, and on my local machine `ls` executes instantly.  However, when I log into one *particular* remote server, and execute `ls` in the home directory only, it takes about 15 seconds to return.  And there's only a few files in the home directory.  If I switch to a sub-directory, or a higher directory, `ls` executes immediately.

Now here's the weird thing: if I use a different computer to access the remote server and run `ls` on the home directory, it returns immediately.

In summary: my particular laptop + one particular remote server + one particular directory = slow ls execution

Any ideas?  Or at least a way to go about debugging this?

EDIT: Okay, more weirdness.  It's only slow on the first execution of ls.  All subsequent executions are fast.  I guess I never bothered to type it again after it was so slow the first time.

Comment: Is it just 'ls' or 'ls -l' that is slow? 'ls -l' needs to stat every file in addition to looking at /etc/passwd (or worse, consult an external user database, where this db is centralized).  In any case, you may run strace on ls and see where the 15 sec pause occurs. This should lead you to the answer.

Comment: Try ls-ing another directory just after logging in, maybe it's the first ls that's problematic - not the home directory.

Comment: @arielf It's just ls.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the part on how to go about debugging this.  Try this in the Linux session:

```
sudo strace ls
```

And pay attention to the system call that hangs for ~15 sec.

(On OS-X one could use 'dtruss', or use dtrace (`man dtrace`))

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified.  I am ssh-ing to a Linux server from OS X.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit difficult to be sure what's going on. Your symptoms *could* be easily explained by a mixture of a real issue (well, not-so-issue) and testing bias.

For example, let's suppose the Linux server is simply idling its disk and the directory you want is not in cache (or maybe it's mounted or linked to a device that is spinned down, as an external disk).

Then the first access requires spin-up/deidling, and there the 15 seconds go.

You go in another directory, and it's fast, because it's either on another device or on the now-spinning device.

You go back to the same directory and now it's fast (the IOSS cache might also have something to do with it).

You logout and login from elsewhere, but *now* the device is still spinning, the cache still primed, and the directory is fast.

To be sure that it's not a problem like this, you would need to wait a suitable time and retry logging in first thing from the *third* computer - the one where `ls` was fast - and check out whether now the `ls` is actually *slow*.

Comment: You make a good point.  I'll give that a try.